# Facebook API to filter user activity to show only specified friends

Tags: java, php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Imaging this situation, I have 1000+ friends on facebook, but I hope to read updates from only a small fraction, eg: 10 close friends. How can I only receive updates from these 10 friends.
I don't know how I can achieve this on Facebook. Can I achieve it using facebook API? (Javascript, PHP, Java, etc..)
Many thanks!

Comment: have you tried looking at the docs at all? https://developer.facebook.com that is the best place to start. Then share with us your attempt. People are more willing to help if you provide some code rather than just ask for a solution

Comment: Yes, I have check the facebook document in the first place, but no luck. I am just wondering if anyone knows the possibility of this plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you've tagged this java,php and javascript but assuming you have the php-sdk you can use an fql query to retrieve the info you want

```
 //assuming $facebook is your php Facebook object
 $fql = url_encode('SELECT status_id, message,uid FROM status WHERE uid in(id1,id2,id3...)');
 $data = $facebook->api('/fql?q='. $fql);
 //data should now hold the response you want, though you will have to match up user names to the uid. I'm assuming you know who the top 10 friends are though and have their id
```

alternatively look at batch requests https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/03/17/batch-requests-in-graph-api/
or an FQL multi query 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/